# How to get current authenticated user in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, security, webflux

I'm trying to retrieve authentication object, which creates user name and permissions.
I know that in WebFlux I cannot use SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), but rather must use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()

But in both cases, result is null.

```
        val autx = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication) // always null
```

or

```
        val auth = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().filter { it.authentication != null }
            .map { it.authentication.principal }.block() // always null
```

I understand, that before retrieve auth object from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder, someone must put it into there.  Cannot find any example how to do that, and where in the code it should be populated.
Ideally, I think it should be in the ReactiveAuthenticationManager implementation in the authenticate method.
I added this into authenticate method:

```
                ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .map { context: SecurityContext ->
                        context.authentication.principal
                    }
                    .cast(UserData::class.java)
                    .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
                    .subscribe()
```

but it doesnt change anything

working examples on Java or Kotlin are appreciated

configuration:

```
@Bean
fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("**/health").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager) // ReactiveAuthenticationManager impl
        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().configurationSource(corsConfig())
        .and()
        .build()
}
```

context repository:

```
@Component
class SecurityContextRepository(
    val authenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager
) : ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    override fun save(swe: ServerWebExchange, sc: SecurityContext): Mono<Void> {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("SecurityContext save not supported")
        // if i want to save, what should be there? 
    }

    override fun load(serverExchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<SecurityContext> {
        val authHeader = serverExchange.request.headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
        val preAuthentication = PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(null, authHeader)
        return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(preAuthentication)
            .map { authentication -> SecurityContextImpl(authentication) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you write the security configuration? May be, SecureContextHolder returns null because authentication object is not set

Comment: updated in the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to define WebFlux Security configuration using `SecurityWebFilterChain` bean. Here is an example for OAuth 2.0 Resource Server:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain apiSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_api")
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    return http.build();
}
```

You can find more details here [WebFlux Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html)

Comment: i have similar configuration, updated in the post.